# How many solutions does this recursive system have?

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, exponential-function, systems-of-equations, recursion

Define the system by:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) = e^{x} \\
f_n(x) = f(xf_{n-1}(\frac{x}{n})) \\
f(x) = f_0(x)
$$
How many solutions $f$ are there?

The solution set is nonempty.  Take $f(x) = 1 + x$.

Is this solution unique?

Comment: $$e^x=f_0(xe^x)$$.Now find solutions  to this